# Program to Invert a hexadecimal number in C

Tags: c, hex, decimal

My Approach:

Step 1. Firstly I converted Hexadecimal number into decimal number. (Hexa to decimal logic)

Then I Invert decimal number's bits using ~ operator and unsigned char datatype variable.

Step 2. And then I convert that decimal number into Hexadecimal number. (decimal to hexa logic)

*Hence i got inverted hexadecimal number.*

*Input and output are string of hexadecimal numbers.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
int
main ()
{
  long decimal, qu, rem;
  int k, j = 0;
  char hexa[100];


  int p = 0;
  int dig, temp;
  unsigned char re = 0;
  char hex[32] = "42";      //input
  int len = strlen (hex);
  len--;
  for (int i = len; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      switch (hex[i])
    {
    case 'A':
      dig = 10;
      break;
    case 'B':
      dig = 11;
      break;
    case 'C':
      dig = 12;
      break;
    case 'D':
      dig = 13;
      break;
    case 'E':
      dig = 14;
      break;
    case 'F':
      dig = 15;
      break;
    default:
      dig = hex[i] - 48;
      break;
    }
      temp = temp + dig * pow (16, p);
      p++;
      re = temp;
      re = ~re;
    }

  qu = re;

  while (qu != 0)
    {
      rem = qu % 16;
      if (rem < 10)
    hexa[j++] = 48 + rem;
      else
    hexa[j++] = 55 + rem;
      qu = qu / 16;
    }

  for (k = j; k >= 0; k--)
    {
      printf ("%c", hexa[k]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What lengths are we talking about ? I mean the hexa string. Is it unknow byte long and have to inverted byte by byte or is it alwas fixed length like 8 digit?

Comment: Length is 8 bits

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: For example if input is 42, and its Binary is 0100 0010. So the output should be 1011 1101 = BD

Comment: @stark That question was asked by the same user which got closed lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Please enter some hex: ");
    unsigned int hex;
    // scan input as hex into an integer
    scanf("%x", &hex);
    // truncate the last byte into a char
    unsigned char c = hex;
    // invert it
    c = ~c;
    // print it back out as uppercase hex
    printf("Inverted hex: %02X\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to say but I didn't get the logic behind this even after seeing those comments. So could u please expain just the logic in short.

Comment: `scanf` reads the input in as hexadecimal into the `hex` variable, then the last byte of `hex` is written into the `c` variable, the `c` variable is inverted via the `~` operator, then `c` is printed out as hex via `printf`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I want is, pre define the value of hex. And don't want to scan it from the user.  I'm learning coding for embedded systems. Example, Unsigned int hex = 42;       //42 for example

Comment: Well then you can just get rid of the scanf and set hex to 0x42.

Comment: And please tell me why you used *unassigned int* for **hex** and *unassigned char* for **c**

Comment: The int doesn't actually need to be unsigned, but the char has to be unsigned otherwise for values greater than 0x80 it'll wrap around and display as negative, which is bad.

Answer (score -1):

Well this maybe enough. This essential doing the same steps what you described, but with less code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char * hex = "42ABE3";
  unsigned dec;

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(hex); i++) {
    sscanf(hex + i, "%1X", &dec);
    printf("%X", 15 - dec);
  }
}
```

Output

```
BD541C
```

Note that this code did not check if `sscanf` was successfull, but you could add that if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I want is, pre define my input. And don't want to scan it from the user. I'm learning coding for embedded systems.

Comment: @Rohit It did not scan from the user. `sscanf` scanning from the string.

Comment: Can you explain sscanf line?

Comment: Same as simple `scanf` but scanning the string `hex`. With `hex + i` the start of the string will be the `i`th character indexing from 0. So if `i = 2` then it will scan from `A` in the example. `"%1X"` will read in one hexa digit as decimal.